# Blinking LED on MPLAB not Working ?

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

am using MPLAB to program my new microchip board and programming it programming it using pickit3

code:

```
// Include the necessary device header file
#include <p18f8722.h>



#pragma config OSC = HSPLL, //OSCS = OFF // HS-PLL Enabled, Internal External Osc. Switch Over OFF Disabled
#pragma config PWRT = OFF // Power Up Timer: OFF Disabled
//#pragma config BOR = OFF, BORV = 25 // Brown Out Reset: OFF, Brown Out Voltage: OFF Disabled
#pragma config WDT = OFF, WDTPS = 128 // Watchdog Timer: OFF Disabled, Watchdog Postscaler: 1:128
//#pragma config CCP2MUX = OFF // CCP2 Mux: OFF Disabled (RB3)
//#pragma config STVR = OFF // Stack Overflow Reset: OFF Disabled
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low Voltage ICSP:OFF Disabled
#pragma config DEBUG = ON // Background Debugger Enable: OFF Disabled
#pragma config CP0 = OFF, CP1 = OFF, CP2 = OFF, CP3 = OFF // Code Protection Block 0-3: OFF Disabled
#pragma config CPB = OFF // Boot Block Code Protection: OFF Disabled
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Code Protection: OFF Disabled
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF, WRT1 = OFF, WRT2 = OFF, WRT3 = OFF // Write Protection Block 0-3: OFF Disabled
#pragma config WRTB = OFF // Boot Block Write Protection: OFF Disabled
#pragma config WRTC = ON // Configuration Register Write Protection: OFF Disabled
#pragma config WRTD = OFF // Data EEPROM Write Protection: OFF Disabled
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF, EBTR1 = OFF, EBTR2 = OFF, EBTR3 = OFF // Table Read Protection Block 0-3: OFF Disabled
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF // Boot Block Table Read Protection: OFF Disabled




// Function prototypes
void delay1(void);

// Main code section. Execution starts here.
void main(void){
 // First some setup code for the LED
 // The LED will be driven by port D, bit 0, driving the anode, cathode to ground

 // First we should clear the port D, bit 0 data latch
 LATDbits.LATD0=0;

 // We need to set port D, bit 0 as an output
 // Using TRISDbits instead of TRISD allows isolating a single bit leaving the other bits unchanged
 TRISDbits.TRISD1=0; // 0 = output, 1 = input

 // Set port D, bit 0 to off (driving the LED anode, cathode to ground)
 PORTDbits.RD1=0;

 // LED blinking loop that never ends since '1' never changes
 while(1){
 PORTDbits.RD1=1; // turn the LED on
 delay1(); // call the delay function
 PORTDbits.RD1=0; // turn the LED off
 delay1(); // call the delay function
 }
 // end of main, but we will never get this far (endless loop)
}

// Start of our functions
void delay1(void){
 /*
 It is important to note that all variable declarations need to be placed before any code in
 a function or the build will fail. 
 */
 // declare a long integer and set it to zero
 long int loop1=0;

 // count from zero to 30,000 then continue on
 // Lower than 30000 for a faster blink, higher for a slower blink.
 for(loop1=0;loop1<=30000;loop1++){


 }
 // The loop is done and execution has moved past the loop
}
```

this code didn't do anything , it compiled perfectly on high tech C compiler but it didn't workout as it was expected ,
maybe the problem is in the configuration bit ? any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the controller and port, I am guessing that you are using the PIC18 Explorer board.  If so, please verify that jumper JP1 is in place.  This must be in place when using the onboard LED's.

If it is not this board, then could you be using the wrong port?  For instance, the "low pin count" demo board I received with my pickit has the LED's on port C, not D.

Comment: I am using PIC18 Explorer board , JP1 is in place ! I tried bits from all the the ports yet no result !

Answer (score 0):

Check if that pin also has an analog capability (ANx).

If it's the case, analog is the default setting and you cannot drive the pin. You should set it in digital mode first.